# Module has no exported member, export interface

Tags: angularjs, typescript

This is the error I'm getting,

> /Users/robot/code/slg-fe/src/app/leaderboards/leaderboards.component.ts
>   (2,10): Module
>   '"/Users/robot/code/slg-fe/src/app/leaderboards/leaderboard"' has no
>   exported member 'Leaderboard'.

My leaderboard.ts file:

```
export interface Leaderboard {
  id: number,
  username: string,
  rank_elo: number,
  role: number,
  total_wins: number,
  kda: number,
  yesterday_rank: number
}
```

My leaderboard.component.ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Leaderboard } from './leaderboard';

@Component({
  selector: 'leaderboards',
  templateUrl: './leaderboards.component.html'
})
export class LeaderboardsComponent { }
```

My leaderboard.ts file IS exporting a Leaderboard, but for some reason it's not?

Comment: Got a demo of the game?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

So.. I'm not sure why, but when I restarted my server it all started working.. I spent so long trying to figure this out.

Comment: It sometimes happen when you already have a local server watching your changes running and then create a new file.

The watch doesn't take the new file into account until it is restarted.

Comment: I got the same error when add a new interface in existing file also. When resstart my editor and build again , the error gone.

Comment: This is still true a year later in Angular 4.3. Just restart your server (localhost or remote)

Comment: Just happened to me as well. Thank you for updating though. I would've been searching for a few more minutes.

Comment: Still true in Angular 7.3. Restarting solved the issue.

Comment: The same problem, new interface and error, restarting solved. 
Well, I lost only half an hour, lucky me ;-). Thank so much

Comment: This behavior is the same with today's webpack hot reloader (vue cli service 4.5)

Answer (score 3):

I had this error for two different imports.

I restarted my server and one of them disappeared. For the other, I deleted the import, built it (with lots of errors), and added the import exactly as it was before.